# Static UIView becomes nil after added to superview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a static view that is used to display as a loading indicator in the UI.

```
static UIView *loadingView;
```

in my class `Loading.m` I add `loadingView` into my container when `show()` is called

```
+ (void)show {
    if (loadingView == nil) {
        UIWindow *containerView = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow;
        
        loadingView = [UIView alloc] init];
        [containerView addSubview:loadingView];
    }
}
```

and when `dismiss()` is called I remove it from superview:

```
+ (void)dismiss {
    if (loadingView != nil) {
        [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
        loadingView = nil;
    }
}
```

I found `loadingView` will always be nil after being added into `containerView`, so I will keep adding more `loadingView` into my `containerView` and it will not be removed when `dismiss()` is called. When I print `UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow` it shows an UIView has been added into the stack. It seems like `loadingView` has lost its reference into `containerView` after `show()` is completed.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you detected that's "loadingView" is nil?

Please verify it via code or using "po" in Debugger.

If you just saw "nil" value in variables list, sometimes it's Xcode debugger bug.
When variable "nil" in variable list, but it's not "nil".

Comment: You are correct , turns out to be a debugger bug , when I po it it shows its not nil , this solves my question, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this question can have deeper consequences:

- You use static `UIView`. If your application is under ARC, system automatically decides if objects can live when they are not visible. So, you should think twice before using `static` declaration for visible objects.
- If your object does respond to messages like `removeFromSuperview` and `.superview` is not `nil` - it means that the object is not `nil` for sure. As said above, it is bug of debugger (happens when running the app on device under XCode).

The goal of this post - to pay attention to the `UIView` objects ierarchy, where parent object has `.subviews` non-null NSArray property, indicating all objects, added as subviews. They will be autoreleased by ARC next to removed from the stack VC. So, in case of `static UIView *` declaration, ARC will keep loaded all its parent elements until it will be manually removed from superview. In other words, `static UIView *` is potentially dangerous construction and can lead to memory leaks or other conflicts. Better way to control loading indicator, for instance - is to check last subview element of current top VC:

```
if (self.view.subviews && [self.view.subviews.lastObject isKindOfClass: [loadview class]]) {
    [self.view.subviews.lastObject removeFromSuperview];
}
```

In this case you have no risk to of calling `nil` object methods (app crashes as well) and headache of manual lifecycle control.